# How to express mathematically the random shuffaling of matrix columns?

Tags: matrices

How to express mathematically the random  shuffaling of matrix columns - say turning $[1, 2, 3]$ into $[3,1,2]$ ?

Comment: This is a permutation.

Comment: Multiply on the right by a permutation matrix.

Comment: They're elements of $S_3$.